# How to select values when data is not grouped?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to select some values to table, but values are not grouped in xml files, structure is as below:

```
<a Name><v index="1">Lawrence</v>
<a Surname><v index="1">Karlton</v>
<a Name><v index="2">Ana</v>
<a Surname><v index="2">Karlton</v>.
<a Avarage><v>75</v>
```

I know how to create a loop when that kind of data is grouped. When I get the file, the max index is unknow. 
On stackoverflow I have found only examples for groups, but maybe I'm missing correct key words.

Comment: I am afraid the markup `<a Name>` is not even well-formed, syntactically correct. As for processing, you have not even shown and explained how the data is related or which data you want to relate. Assuming the `index` attribute is an indicator that elements belong together you can of course group elements by that value, using `for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0/3.0 or Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0. So explain which output you want, after fixing the sample to show well-formed XML, and then I am sure XSLT can help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with bringing your XML to a proper shape.

If a tag (in your case `a`) contains an attribute, then this attribute must have a value (after "=").
Each `a` tag must alse be closed (contain "/" char before the final ">".

So (probably) your source XML, including a top level tag, should look something like this:

```
<main>
  <a attr="Name"/><v index="1">Lawrence</v>
  <a attr="Surname"/><v index="1">Karlton</v>
  <a attr="Name"/><v index="2">Ana</v>
  <a attr="Surname"/><v index="2">Karlton</v>
  <a attr="Average"/><v>75</v>
</main>
```

Let's make another assumption, that each source "record" starts with `<a attr="Name"/>`
and continues up to the next `<a attr="Name"/>` or to the end of the parent tag,
whichever occurs first.

In such case you can:

- Write a template, matching `main` tag.
- Use a `xsl:for-each-group` loop with:

  - `select="*"` - take all child tags,
  - `group-starting-with="a[@attr='Name']"` - each group starts with `<a attr="Name"/>`.

Then, based on the content of each group, you can e.g.:

- Start the current row (write opening `tr` tag) - I assume, you generate an
  HTML `table`.
- For each output column:

  - Retrieve source `a` tag with particular value or `attr` attribute (equal
    to the output column name).
  - Take the value of this column from the next sibling `v` tag.
- Close the current row (write closing `tr` tag).